# how to return a string in a specific format in classes?

Tags: function, class, python-3.x

Let's say I have a class of Books which I already defined the **init**. I want my **str** to return the books in this format:

'Book("Dr.!Seuss",!"The!Cat!in!the!Hat",!"12345")'

I have this:

```
def __str__(self):
   return 'Books( title={0}'.format(self.title)
```

I haven't checked if it works. Which is another question. How do I check if it works as in how do I create something that contains books?

Comment: When you say, "something that contains books", do you mean something like an array?  Why can't you just test it with a single Book to verify your method is correct?

Comment: @ATG what is an array?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
li=['Dr.','Seuss','The','Cat','in','the','Hat','12345']
print('Book({})'.format('!'.join(li)))
```